# Анимированные действия в Gmail

Tags: touch, android, listview, java, sliding

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как и при помощи чего реализована вот такая вещь:

[image]

Получается что к `ListView` через `addHeaderView` добавили некий хедер. Но, вопрос, как они отслеживают что идет утягивание списка вниз и в этот момент перекрывается `ActionBar` текстовым полем с надписью "Пролистните вниз, чтобы обновить"?
Поиск по ключевым словам в гугле особого успеха не дал.

Второй вопрос: как сделано удаление `Item`'a через слайд в сторону?

[image]

Я реализовал эту функцию через [`android-swipetodismiss`](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/2980593), но это не оригинальное решение команды `Google` и оно имеет несколько недостатков в отличии от реализации `Gmail`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

могу посоветовать только по первому поглядеть вот это либу https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh
у самого прикрутить не вышло быстро, а так как не было острой необходимости, то и бросил.